# Solve Image display sizing issue for thumbnails

Tags: html, css, image, thumbnails

[image: Deals Page]

I am trying to build a deals page which are pulled from amazon.in.I basically go to a deal and copy the image and upload to my server.
But due to different size of the images on amazon.in when I shrink it by 200*200 size for the deal thumbnail, some of the images are getting distorted.

In the below image you can see that the Amazon Basics cable is properly scaled, where as the iphone 7 image is distorted due to the nature of images at amazon.in.
What is the general recommendation for these problems? How do we solve this issue so that I get uniform images for my deals?

Comment: So you mean to crop the image and then resize ?

Comment: Fix the width and place the image in a div with `oveflow:none` and fixed height to hide the extra height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** the image does not have an **aspect ratio of 1:1** (which is the ratio for your thumbnails) **it will get distorted** because there's more length in one dimension than the other and if try to match them, one of them will have to be squeezed. That's where the distortion comes from.

**The only thing that will work is to give the images a new aspect ratio that matches your template**

This *can* be done with **CSS** like **@SaidbakR** mentioned in the comments

> Fix the width and place the image in a div with oveflow:none and fixed height to hide the extra height.

This will work beautifully but some images will just not work. They will just be cutoff in the wrong places.

The only other thing you can do is to **manually edit the photos** in Photoshop or something similar. **This can work on all images**, but manually **editing each and every photo that doesn't fit is a pain in the neck.**

nevertheless, *here's what you end up with.*

**Before:** Original Image in full dimensions

[image: image in full size]

**After:** Image edited in a program like Photoshop to the desired size of 200x200 with no distortion

[image]

So? My Suggested **fix is to adjust your approach/template or find another source for your images.**